# Equivalence of Conditional Expectations w.r.t. Discrete Random Variable

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ and $Y$ be integrable random variables such that $P(Y=y) > 0$ for all $y \in Y(\Omega)$.  Then the conditional expectation of $X$ given $Y=y$ is defined as
$$
\mathrm E[X \mid Y=y] : = \frac{\mathrm E[1_{\{Y=y\}}X]}{P(Y=y)}.
$$
OTOH, it is also defined as
$$
\mathrm E[X \mid Y=y] : = \int_\Omega X(\omega) \, P^Y(\mathrm d\omega \mid y),
$$
where $P^Y(\cdot \mid \cdot)$ is the regular conditional probability of $P$ given $Y$.  **I'm having trouble showing their equivalence**, and all I currently understand is that we're trying to show the following:

Since
$$
P(Y=y) = \int_\Omega 1_{\{Y=y\}}(\omega) \, P(\mathrm d\omega)
$$ 
and 
$$\mathrm E[1_{\{Y=y\}}X] = \int_\Omega 1_{\{Y=y\}}(\omega) X(\omega) \, P(\mathrm d\omega),
$$  so we're trying to show
$$
\int_\Omega 1_{\{Y=y\}}(\omega) \, P(\mathrm d\omega) \cdot \int_\Omega X(\omega) \, P^Y(\mathrm d\omega \mid y) = \int_\Omega 1_{\{Y=y\}}(\omega) X(\omega) \, P(\mathrm d\omega).
$$
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $P(Y=y) >0$ for all $y \in \mathbb R$? Do you really mean this?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Edited that part, thanks.

Comment: Follows from the very definition of $P^Y$ as $$P^Y(\ \mid y)=P(Y=y)^{-1}\mathbf 1_{Y=y}P$$

Comment: @Did Would you mind elaborating why this is the definition of $P^Y$?

Comment: Is it not? When $P(Y=y)\ne0$, the regular conditional probability becomes simple.

Comment: @Did It's not clear to me what you wrote.  What is $\mathbf 1_{Y=y} P$?  Indeed if $P(Y=y) \neq 0$ then $P(X \in A \mid Y = y) = \frac{P(X \in A \cap Y = y)}{P(Y=y)}$, but I'm not sure how to use this.

Comment: Hmmm, then let us recall some definition: the measure $\mathbf 1_{Y=y}P$ is the measure $Q$ on $\Omega$ with Radon-Nykodym derivative $\mathbf 1_{Y=y}$ with respect to $P$. That is, for every event $A$, $$Q(A)=E_P(\mathbf 1_{Y=y}\mathbf 1_A)=P(A\cap\{Y=y\})$$ and for every (integrable or nonnegative random variable $Z$, $$\int_\Omega ZdQ=\int_\Omega Z\mathbf 1_{Y=y}dP=\int_{Y=y}ZdP=E(Z\mathbf 1_{Y=y}).$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26199/discussion-between-bcf-and-did).

Comment: @Did Is $P$ a probability measure on $\Omega$? If so I don't see how $\mathbf 1_{Y=y}$ qualifies as a Radon-Nikodym derivative, since the total mass of the measure $Q$ need not be 1: $$Q(\Omega) = \int_\Omega \mathrm 1_{Y=y}dP = P(Y=y)$$

Comment: Sorry but what are you talking about? Precisely because the total mass of the measure $Q$ need not be $1$, the random variable $\mathbf 1_{Y=y}$ "qualifies" as the RN derivative $dQ/dP$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $$P^y(X \in A) = P^Y(X \in A \mid y) = \frac{\int 1_{\{Y = y\}}1_{A}X(\omega) \, d P(\omega)}{P(Y = y)}$$ 
Note that for simple functions $s_n(x) = \sum_{k = 1}^N a_i 1_{A_i}(x) $ we have

$$\Bbb{E}[s_n(X) \vert Y = y] = \Bbb{E}^{P^Y}[s_n(X)] = \sum_{k = 1}^N a_i P^y(X \in A_i) = \sum_{k=1}^N a_i \frac{\int 1_{\{Y = y\}}1_{A_i}X(\omega) \, d P(\omega)}{P(Y = y)} = \frac{\int 1_{\{Y = y\}} \sum_{k=1}^N a_i1_{A_i}X(\omega) \, d P(\omega)}{P(Y = y)}= \frac{\int 1_{\{Y = y\}} s_n(X)(\omega) \, d P(\omega)}{P(Y = y)} $$

now take $s_n(x) \uparrow Id(x)$ where $Id(x) = x$ and use the monotone convergence theorem

$$\int_\Omega X(\omega) \, P^Y(\mathrm d\omega \mid y)= \Bbb{E}[X \vert Y = y] = \lim_{n}\Bbb{E}[s_n(X) \vert Y = y]  = \frac{\lim_{n}\int 1_{\{Y = y\}} s_n(X)(\omega) \, d P(\omega)}{P(Y = y)}  = \frac{\int 1_{\{Y = y\}} X(\omega) \, d P(\omega)}{P(Y = y)} = \frac{\mathrm E[1_{\{Y=y\}}X]}{P(Y=y)}. $$